# Programmatically add a file to jquery fileupload

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, blueimp

I'm using [blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/) to allow users to upload attachments when creating a inquiry on my site.

I need to extend the current functionality to add a auto generated image to the queue. The image I need to add is an exported canvas, thus a base64 encoded string, i.e something like

data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNby
// blAAAADElEQVQImWNgoBMAAABpAAFEI8ARAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC

How can I add such a file to the upload queue? I am stuck and don't know where to start. Any pointers to the right direction is much appreciated.

Comment: you mean to say set image file?i doubt its possible because of security reasons

Comment: @guradio Not sure what you mean but probably. So the only way would be to pass it to my back end in a separate post or something? I failed to mention that it's not supposed to end up on my servers but on amazon S3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to programmatically add a `File` object to `FileList` object at `<input type="file">` element.  You can create a file as `data URI`; `Blob` or `File`; or `FormData` object, use `POST` to send file object to server.

Comment: Thank you! That's what I feared.